# How can I set multiple env variables pointing to the same value on docker?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have several containers that I run together with docker-compose.
One of them, is mysql, which requires some variables to be set. I have those in a `.env` file:

```
MYSQL_USER='my_user'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='my_password'
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='supersecretpassword'
MYSQL_DATABASE='my_database'
```

And I am able to start the mysql container successfully.

The problem comes when I want to use another service for db migrations, which require the following variables set in the `.env` file:

```
SERVICE_DBUSER='my_user'
SERVICE_DBPASSWORD='my_password'
SERVICE_DBNAME='my_database'
```

And what I would like to write (**this doesn't work**), to avoid repetition, is something like:

```
SERVICE_DBUSER="$MYSQL_USER"
SERVICE_DBPASSWORD="$MYSQL_PASSWORD"
SERVICE_DBNAME="$MYSQL_DATABASE"
```

But docker doesn't recognize that and doesn't perform the substitution. In the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), it also states that `expects each line in an env file to be in VAR=VAL format`.

My question is, is it possible to avoid the repetition?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Compose will [substitute environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/variable-substitution) into the YAML compose file when you reference them with `$VARIABLE` or `${VARIABLE}`.

You can still use the `.env` file to set a default environment. But when you want to reference a variable, put it in the `environment:` section of the compose yaml:

```
environment:
  SERVICE_DBUSER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
  SERVICE_DBPASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
  SERVICE_DBNAME: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
```

Then if you set, or source an alternate environment when running `docker-compose` you will get the new values substituted in.

```
$ MYSQL_USER="other" MYSQL_PASSWORD="opass" docker-compose start
```